# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module Typescript Error

Tags: javascript, typescript, importerror, tsconfig, react-typescript

I have multiple .ts files and I am getting some typescript errors in them regarding importing some modules/scripts.

Consider the following example:

```
Sample1.ts
--------

const axios = require('axios');

function sample1() {
...
...

}

Sample2.ts
--------

const axios = require('axios');

function sample2() {
...
...

}
```

These two .ts files are in one folder. I get an error in file sample2.ts saying

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'axios'.ts(2451)
```

To resolve this error I changed this line `const axios = require('axios');` to `import axios from 'axios';` to an import statement. But for the import statement, I get the error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

My module and target in tsconfig file is esnext and es6 respectively.

Please can someone help me with this problem. I ma trying to remove these errors for a very long time.

Comment: perhaps adding type: module at your package.json will enable the import syntax

Answer (score 0):

In the `package.json` file, add the top-level "type" field with a value of "module".

```js
// package.json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```